# Voltage Follower not working for low resistance loads

Tags: operational-amplifier, resistance, impedance

I have simulated a bridge-tied load, which is to be tied to an ultrasonic transducer. The part I'm worried about is the part where the BTL touches the transducer itself.

[image]

As one can see, the transducer is tied to the two voltage followers. The inputs of the two voltage followers U3 and U4 are out of sync and these inputs, when R5 (the transducer) is of adequate resistance, would remain out of sync, like so.

[image]

For reasons related to how current and impedance works, these two voltage followers' outputs becomes more similar the closer one gets to a low impedance. This shouldn't be surprising.

[image: This was done with R5 set to 2 ohms. Not practical but it's there to demonstrate.]

My question is that are there any methods that allow the load R5 to retain the two signals it receives while it has a low resistance? Anything to tell the voltage to expend all of itself on R5 and not go through R5? Preferably without changing the op-amps.

The entire schematic that the first picture is from. I don't know how much this can help. Please ignore U1 that's disconnected. All other opamps are from LTSpice's UniversalOpamp3.
[image]

Comment: *"Anything to tell the voltage to expend all of itself on R5 and not go through R5?"* Do you mean what kind of op. amp. will be able to drive a 2 Ohm load?

Comment: More specifically, what kind of op. amp. will be able to drive a low resistance load (2 Ohm was just a random example, my application is unlikely to reach that low) while another identical op. amp. drives an inverted but otherwise identical load through it.
Though I don't think this is caused by the op. amps not being good since I'm simulating the circuit with LTSpice's own universal op. amps.

Comment: The simulation doesn't look right, you shouldn't have any floating nodes in a simulation, so delete U1.  U2 U3 U4 U5 have no model as shown in the sim, if you do have a model, make sure the text is in the screenshot

Comment: I am using LTSpice's UniversalOpamp3, that may be why they have no model shown in the sim. As for U1, I can remove it.

Comment: LTSpice's "universal" op-amps still simulate typical small signal op-amps.  If you look at the op-amps parameters, you should see an output resistance or an output current limit.  Set the resistance lower or the current limit higher, and things will work.  In the real world, select a power op-amp (such things exist), or use an op-amp driving an output stage made with discrete transistors.

Comment: Careful, a piezo transducer behaves more like a capacitor than a resistor.  Many op-amps have trouble driving capacitive loads.

Comment: @HFOrangefish Change limit=25m to limit=200m on U4 and U3 and see if that helps